# Kubernetes. HTTPS API return `Unauthorized`

Tags: curl, docker, kubernetes, tls1.2

Kubernetes API request `curl https://192.168.0.139 --cacert /home/mongeo/ku-certs/ca.pem` return `Unauthorized`

Request `curl localhost:8080` worked good.

My kube-proxy and kube-apiserver standart ([coreos+k8s tutorial](https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/deploy-master.html))

How do I get data on HTTPS?

Comment: add 443 port address for https

Comment: try curl https://192.168.0.139:443 --cacert /home/mongeo/ku-certs/ca.pem

Comment: @ShivSingh Singh It does not help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you specify `--token-auth-file=<file>` and/or `--basic-auth-file=<otherfile>` or one of the other authentication modes?  I don't know that https endpoint will work without one of these (maybe it should, but it doesn't, apparently).  Check out https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authentication/

Comment: How it will help open the page in a browser? The token must be passed in cheder page requests?

Answer (score 3):

Hi this is what I did for token,

1. Find address Server Api

   - open `/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf`

     *example: `server: https://10.1.32.120:6443`*
2. Find token

   - open `/etc/kubernetes/pki/tokens.csv`

     *example: `4c95a1a22d19b20811,kubeadm-node-csr,07ccbf35-e206-11e6-ab8f-0010184e550e,system:kubelet-bootstrap`*
3. In this case the token is `4c95a1a22d19b20811`
4. If use postman, add header `Authorization: Bearer 4c95a1a22d19b20811`

Comment: i can't find token.csv in my /etc/kubernetes/pki/ directory. Do we need to add the token file ourselves??

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to access the Kubernetes API from an external network is to create an [SSH tunnel](http://blog.trackets.com/2014/05/17/ssh-tunnel-local-and-remote-port-forwarding-explained-with-examples.html), e.g.

```
ssh -L 9000:localhost:8080 roto@master.node
```

This will forward connection from your local port `9000` to `localhost:8080` on your server.

As long as the SSH tunnel is open, you can query the API on port `9000` of your machine.

Comment: `kubectl proxy` is an easier way to establish a local http tunnel to the API server.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to authenticate in the API. Simplest way for you to get authorized is to send Authentication header with "bearer TOKEN_VALUE" value. You can look at Kubernetes API configuration on your server to look up defined tokens. The header can be sent with http request using web browser extension.

Answer (score 0):

finally, i figured this out:

```
lincai@pdbuddy:~/blackbox$ curl -v --cacert ./ca.pem --key ./admin-key.pem --cert ./admin.pem  https://xxxx/api/v1/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache

> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Comment: Great! If you want to use a file  from  the  current  directory,  please precede it with "./" prefix, in order to avoid confusion with a nickname.

Comment: I observed that in my environment, if i dont use "./" prefix, I get unauthorized error. I am running the command from the folder where there are certificates so why does it not work ? This is what I am trying and it did not work `curl https://x:x:x::6443/api/ --key kubernetes.key --cert kubernetes.crt --cacert ca.crt` and this works `curl https://x:x:x::6443/api/ --key ./kubernetes.key --cert ./kubernetes.crt --cacert ./ca.crt`

Answer (score -3):

```
curl https://192.168.0.139 —key ./admin-key.pem —cert ./admin.pem —cacert ./ca.pem
```

Comment: Add an explanation for the OP. It will help him understand better.