# How to access dashboard service internal use Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, alibaba-cloud, alibaba-cloud-ecs

I have `kubernetes-dashboard` service with type is `ClusterIP`. How can I access dashboard internal? I use Alibaba Cloud.

My service.yml

```
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  labels:
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    app: kubernetes-dashboard
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 9090
  selector:
    app: kubernetes-dashboard
```

I would like to run my dashboard at http://MASTER_IP:80

The status when running `kubectl cluster-info`:

```
Kubernetes master is running at https://MASTER_IP:6443
Heapster is running at https://MASTER_IP:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/heapster/proxy
KubeDNS is running at https://MASTER_IP:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns/proxy
kubernetes-dashboard is running at https://MASTER_IP:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard/proxy
monitoring-influxdb is running at https://MASTER_IP:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/monitoring-influxdb/proxy
```

When I access `https://MASTER_IP:6443`, I got the error `default backend - 404`.

Note: Don't use NodePort and `kubectl proxy`.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change the dashboard service type to **NodePort** then you can access dashboard with any cluster :

1. change service type from ClusterIP to NodePort
   `kubectl -n kube-system edit svc kubernetes-dashboard`
2. Get the service port number.

   `kubectl -n kube-system get svc kubernetes-dashboard -o yaml |grep nodePort`
3. Access dahboard with https://masererverIP:nodeportnumber

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't use NotePort or `kubectl proxy` in this case.

Comment: How about another solution?

Answer (score 0):

[In this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48286170/how-to-access-canonical-kubernetes-dashboard-externally/48286677#48286677) you can find the different ways to access the dashboard.

If you are not using `NodePort` or `kubectl proxy`, your best options are

### API Server

In case Kubernetes API server is exposed and accessible from outside you can directly access dashboard at: `https://<master-ip>:<apiserver-port>/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/`

### Ingress

Dashboard can be also exposed using Ingress resource. For example

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
 name: kubernetes-dashboard-ingress
 namespace: kube-system
spec:
 rules:
   — host: kubernetes
     http:
       paths:
         — path: /ui
           backend:
             serviceName: kubernetes-dashboard
             servicePort: 80
```

Comment: Thanks @fiunchinho, I try to add Ingress to my cluster, but it's not working. Please help me more about it. About API server, how to get port?

Comment: This blog post could help you deploy and use the nginx Ingress controller https://medium.com/@gokulc/setting-up-nginx-ingress-on-kubernetes-2b733d8d2f45. You can find the ip's of your nodes running `kubectl get nodes -o yaml`