# Kubernetes Dashboard accessing outside the cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-dashboard

We have a kubernetes environment(3 EC2 instances). I am trying to access the dashboard from outside the cluster, but its showing site can't be reached. So that i gone to some links and found through nginx-ingress we can access it.

[I have gone to this url](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/blob/master/deployments/deployment/nginx-ingress.yaml) and installed nginx.

And i have created this file to access.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
    nginx.org/ssl-backends: "kubernetes-dashboard"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
  name: dashboard-ingress
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  rules:
  - host: serverdnsname
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /dashboard
        backend:
          serviceName: kubernetes-dashboard
          servicePort: 443
```

But still not able to access it.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39864385/how-to-access-expose-kubernetes-dashboard-service-outside-of-a-cluster) thread?

Answer (score 1):

We managed it like this

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 9090
  selector:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
```

just added a clusterip service and use a nginx before it as a reverse proxy

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name kubernetes.dev.xxxxx;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/kubernetes.dev.xxxx/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/kubernetes.dev.xxxx/privkey.pem;

    include ssl.conf;

    location / {
        deny all;
        include headers.conf;

        resolver 10.96.0.10 valid=30s; #ip of your dns service inside the cluster
        set $upstream kubernetes-dashboard.kube-system.svc.cluster.local;
        proxy_pass http://$upstream;
    }
}
```

but should also be possible with NodePort

Answer (score 0):

I did not try it with Ingress, but you probably know that as a quick but not necessarily a good solution, you can also expose it as NodePort?